# Why my headers are getting repeated in SQL plus

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I have a Table in **Oracle** : Employee

The Employee table `N` number of records

My issue is after 14th records it prints Headers again

```
SQLPLUS -S -M "HTML ON TABLE 'BORDER="2"'" HR@Ora10g @employee.sql>data_employee.html
```

**Query in :** `employee.sql`

```
SELECT *
FROM EMPLOYEE;
EXIT
```

**Output :**

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cFtt.png)

**Expected Output :**
[Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63BL3.png)

Answer (score 0):

Enlarge *page size* with e.g.

```
set pagesize 200
```

and then run the query again.

If you set it to `0`, heading won't repeat, but it won't be displayed either (at all). So, find a value that suits your needs and use it.

---

As you wonder which are MIN and MAX allowed values, here you go (for 11g database version):

```
SQL> set pagesize -2
SP2-0267: pagesize option -2 out of range (0 through 50000)
```

Comment: is it going to work if their are 1000 records ... can you what is the meaning of pagesize 200

Comment: What is the maximum page size i can set and minimum page size

Comment: Pagesize 200 means that headings will repeat every 200 records. For more info, see updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

The default pagesize in SQLPlus is 14 lines per page. You can change that by adding the following command at the top of your SQL script:

```
set pagesize 0
```

`0` disables the paging.

Comment: what is the purpose of pagesize 0 , is it going to print only once the header .

Comment: "what is the purpose of pagesize 0".  Well, you _could_ look it up in the SQL+Plus Reference Manual.